# make given matrix zero centered

Tags: matlab, matrix

suppose that we have following matrix

```
A=rand(4,3)

A =

    0.9572    0.4218    0.6557
    0.4854    0.9157    0.0357
    0.8003    0.7922    0.8491
    0.1419    0.9595    0.9340
```

i want to calculate means of each columns of matrix and then subtract these means from original matrix,so i have calculates means

```
  b=mean(A)

b =

    0.5962    0.7723    0.6186
```

as i know to subtract means,we should use  something like this

```
 A-repmat(b,1,3)
Error using  - 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

but it shows me error,so please help me what is problem?

Comment: `bsxfun(@minus,A,mean(A))`

Comment: or this one also will work right  A-repmat(mean(A),size(A,1),1)

Comment: @Divakar nice solution. Shouldn't you post it as an answer so the question can be closed and the answer easier to spot?

Comment: yes please  and also please consider row case

Comment: use `A - repmat(b,4,1)` instead of `A-repmat(b,1,3)` .

Comment: @datodatuashvili for row case i would recommend to transpose the matrix (before doing the calculation) and another transpose of the answer.

Comment: A-repmat(b,1,4)
Error using  - 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Comment: @datodatuashvili That must work too! I would encourage you to post a solution with `bsxfun` and your `repmat` implementations.

Comment: i have posted it  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134559/repmat-function-does-not-work-properly

Comment: @datodatuashvili `bsxfun` usually outperforms `repmat` for cases like this. I would recommend that you go that route instead.

Comment: @datodatuashvili You can post your own solution to this question with your `repmat` and the earlier suggested `bsxfun` implementations, so as to "close" this question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

my answer in this case  after several recommendation and helping,is following

```
A=rand(4,3)

A =

    0.7094    0.6551    0.9597
    0.7547    0.1626    0.3404
    0.2760    0.1190    0.5853
    0.6797    0.4984    0.2238
```

and solutions

```
A-repmat(B,4,1)

ans =

    0.1044    0.2963    0.4324
    0.1497   -0.1962   -0.1869
   -0.3289   -0.2398    0.0580
    0.0748    0.1396   -0.3035
```

and another approaches

```
 bsxfun(@minus,A,mean(A))

    ans =

        0.1044    0.2963    0.4324
        0.1497   -0.1962   -0.1869
       -0.3289   -0.2398    0.0580
        0.0748    0.1396   -0.3035
```

thanks guys very much