# repmat function does not work properly

Tags: matlab, matrix, algebra

let us consider following  situation,for instance we have given matrix and we want to make zero centered  this matrix in columns,so

```
A=rand(4,3)

A =

    0.6948    0.4387    0.1869
    0.3171    0.3816    0.4898
    0.9502    0.7655    0.4456
    0.0344    0.7952    0.6463
```

now this two method works properly

```
A-repmat(mean(A),size(A,1),1)

ans =

    0.1957   -0.1565   -0.2553
   -0.1820   -0.2137    0.0476
    0.4511    0.1703    0.0035
   -0.4647    0.1999    0.2042
```

and also

```
bsxfun(@minus,A,mean(A))

ans =

    0.1957   -0.1565   -0.2553
   -0.1820   -0.2137    0.0476
    0.4511    0.1703    0.0035
   -0.4647    0.1999    0.2042
```

but somehow following method does not  work

```
B=mean(A)

B =

    0.4991    0.5953    0.4421

 A-repmat(B,1,4)

ans =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

i have tried transpose but

```
A-repmat(B,1,4)'
Error using  - 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

also i have tried following

```
A-repmat(B,1,3)'
Error using  - 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

>> A-repmat(B,1,3)
Error using  - 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
 so what is problem of  failure of this method?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not using proper syntax for the repmat function

In your example ,You need to create a matrix of size `4 x 3` using `repmat`

Now a call to `repmat(A,k,j)` repeats matrix `A` `k` times along the first dimension (i.e vertically) and `j` times along the second dimension (i.e, horizontally).

Here, you need to repeat matrix `mean` 4 times in first dimension and 1 time in second dimension .

Hence, the correct call to repmat is `repmat(mean,4,1)`

```
repmat(B,4,1)

ans =

    0.4991    0.5953    0.4421
    0.4991    0.5953    0.4421
    0.4991    0.5953    0.4421
    0.4991    0.5953    0.4421
```

It looks like you need to know why your method is failing

```
repmat(B,1,4) %// returns a 1x12 matrix while A is 3x4 matrix hence dimensions do not agree while using @minus
ans =

    0.4991    0.5953    0.4421   0.4991    0.5953    0.4421   0.4991    0.5953    0.4421   0.4991    0.5953    0.4421
```